# Free software for automatically drawing UML from Python source code

Tags: gratis, open-source, python, uml

Can you suggest a free software or open source library that *automatically* draw a UML given Python source code as input?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am really sorry, can someone explain what's wrong with my question, please? I will be very glad to edit it accordingly. It seems very specific to me. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps that cannot exist, because Python's object model is probably incompatible with UML. However, Python has [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), and if your code is following some documented guidelines, you might make such a tool yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyreverse could be a solution as stated [here](https://charlesreid1.com/wiki/Pyreverse):

> Pyreverse is a tool in the Pylint tool suite. Pyreverse is a tool for
> generating UML diagrams from Python source code.

It can be easily run in the following way:

```
pyreverse -o png my_class.py
```

Answer (score 3):

I found links to several python-specific open-source alternatives for UML generation from source code [here](https://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#python). The Communnity version is still free, open-sourced, and full-featured.

The one that has been updated most recently is [Pynsource](https://pynsource.com/index.html). The description for the original link reads:  "Reverse engineer python source code into UML. Generated UML class diagrams can be displayed as ASCII Art or in a more typical graphical form. After a few years in a zombie state, we have just seen a new and improved version this 2019."